# problemas con sobreposicion elementos

Tags: html, css

Tengo una página web con un `<select>` de unos 20 elementos y bajo él tengo 6 o 7 `<textbox>`.

El caso es que, por defecto, el navegador muestra todos los `<option>` del `<select>` posibles en función de la resolución de pantalla y si no se pueden ver todos muestra un scroll horizontal. Si lo dejo tal cual, cuando despliego el `<select>` los `<options>`, quedan encima de los `textbox`, lo que es normal, pero si hago esto:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
 <div id="Contenedor_select1"  style="z-index:10; width:200px">
  <select id="select1" 
   onchange="this.size=1; this.blur();" 
   onblur="this.size=1;" 
   onfocus="this.size=6;" 
   style="width:200px; text-indent:0px; z-index:10;">
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="01" selected="">Opcion1</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="02" selected="">Opcion2</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="03" selected="">Opcion3</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="04" selected="">Opcion4</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="05" selected="">Opcion5</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="06" selected="">Opcion6</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="07" selected="">Opcion7</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="08" selected="">Opcion8</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="09" selected="">Opcion9</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="10" selected="">Opcion10</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="11" selected="">Opcion11</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="12" selected="">Opcion12</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="13" selected="">Opcion13</option>
    <option  style="z-index:10" value="14" selected="">Opcion14</option>
  </select>
 </div>

 <div  style="z-index:0">
  <div  style="z-index:0">
   Number Box:
  </div>
  <input 
   onfocus="Keyboard(this.id,0,3,null)" 
   style="width:150px; z-index:0" 
   value="0" 
   maxlength="3" 
   id="Nbox" 
   type="text">
 </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Para que cuando se desplieguen los `<option>` se muestren sólo 6 opciones y muestre el scroll para el resto, los `<option>` me quedan debajo de los `textbox` y no se ven.

He intentado solucionarlo con `z-index`, pero no hay manera.

¿Alguna idea de por qué al hacer esto los `<option>` quedan debajo de los `textbox`?.

Comment: Ese código HTML está mal porque no cierras correctamente las comillas. ¿Podrías darnos un ejemplo funcional para que podamos reproducir y arreglar tu problema? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una captura de pantalla o algo que muestre qué problema tienes? He forzado una capa superior con altura máxima para que aparezca el scroll y no logro entender qué te ocurre o qué problema tienes o qué quieres que ocurra cuando pulsas en las opciones.

Comment: hay un boton con el que puedes ejecutar el codigo que he insertado, se ve perfectamente que el div del textbox se desplaza hacia abajo cuando abro el select. Eso es loq ue pasa, si quitas las tres lineas que hacen de limitador (onchange="this.size=1; this.blur();" 
   onblur="this.size=1;" 
   onfocus="this.size=6;")   ese desplazamiento no existe pero se muestran las 14 opciones.

Comment: Ese botón te lo he agregado yo. Entonces entiendo que lo que no quieres es que al cambiar el tamaño del select no baje el texto inferior, ¿cierto? Ten en cuenta que al cambiar `size` estás también cambiando la forma en la que se visualiza el `select`, no sólo indicando cuántos elementos quieres ver.

Comment: efectivamente, eso es lo que no quiero hacer, lo que quiero hacer es limitar a 6 el numero de options que se muestran al desplegarse el select y el resto de options que queden con scroll. Pero, sin desplazar nada de lo que le rodea.

Comment: Te redacté una respuesta hace un momento. ¿Podrías echar un vistazo si es lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución podría ser darle altura al `<div>` que contiene al `<select>` para que desplace el resto de elementos hacia abajo la altura de éste.

Al `<select>` habría que indicarle que use una posición absoluta. Al hacerlo su tamaño ya no afectaría al tamaño del `<div>` que lo contiene y podría salirse de los límites de éste sin provocar desbordamiento:

```html
<div>
    <div>Number Box:</div>
    <input style="width: 150px;" value="0" maxlength="3" id="Nbox" type="text">
</div>
<div id="Contenedor_select1" style="width: 200px; height: 25px;">
    <select id="select1"
            onchange="this.size=1; this.blur();"
            onblur="this.size = 1;"
            onfocus="this.size = 6;"
            style="width: 200px; text-indent: 0px; position: absolute;">
        <option value="01" selected="">Opcion1</option>
        <option value="02" selected="">Opcion2</option>
        <option value="03" selected="">Opcion3</option>
        <option value="04" selected="">Opcion4</option>
        <option value="05" selected="">Opcion5</option>
        <option value="06" selected="">Opcion6</option>
        <option value="07" selected="">Opcion7</option>
        <option value="08" selected="">Opcion8</option>
        <option value="09" selected="">Opcion9</option>
        <option value="10" selected="">Opcion10</option>
        <option value="11" selected="">Opcion11</option>
        <option value="12" selected="">Opcion12</option>
        <option value="13" selected="">Opcion13</option>
        <option value="14" selected="">Opcion14</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <div>Number Box:</div>
    <input style="width: 150px;" value="0" maxlength="3" id="Nbox" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <div>Number Box:</div>
    <input style="width: 150px;" value="0" maxlength="3" id="Nbox" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <div>Number Box:</div>
    <input style="width: 150px;" value="0" maxlength="3" id="Nbox" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <div>Number Box:</div>
    <input style="width: 150px;" value="0" maxlength="3" id="Nbox" type="text">
</div>
```

De la [documentación de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position#Valores):

> **absolute**
>
> No deja espacio para el elemento. En su lugar, lo posiciona en unas coordenadas determinadas relativas a la posición más cercana de su elemento padre o del bloque contenedor inicial.

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar, sale perfecto. Yo creia que posicion absoluta era respecto al body y no respecto al div contenedor.

Comment: Mientras no cambies los atributos `top`, `bottom`, `left` y `right` no se cambiará la posición inicial del elemento. He añadido información adicional que proviene de la documentación de mozilla acerca del comportamiento de `absolute`. Lo importante es que al usar `absolute` no se reserva espacio para el elemento, impidiendo que se mueva el resto del documento para adaptarse a sus cambios. Eso no ocurre con el comportamiento normal de un `<select>`, pero en tu caso, al cambiar el aspecto, es necesario hacerlo.